# Autodesk forge activity "Gateway Timeout" activating master view

Tags: autodesk-forge

Activating master view as in [MasterView](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/new-rvt-svf-model-derivative-parameter-generates-additional-content-including-rooms-and-spaces) I created:

```
            var advOutputPayload = new JobSvf2OutputPayloadAdvanced();
            advOutputPayload.GenerateMasterViews = true;

            // prepare the payload
            List<JobPayloadItem> outputs = new List<JobPayloadItem>()
                                {
                                    new JobPayloadItem(
                                        JobPayloadItem.TypeEnum.Svf,
                                        new List<JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum>()
                                        {
                                            JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum._2d,
                                            JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum._3d
                                        },
                                        advOutputPayload
                                    )
                                };


            JobPayload obJob = new JobPayload(new JobPayloadInput(b64(info.revitFileUrn)), new JobPayloadOutput(outputs));
```

then I call with 'x-ads-force: true' using the SDK:

```
dynamic jobPosted = await derivative.TranslateAsync(jobPayload, force);
```

Where force is set to true.

And sometimes it works perfectly fine but sometimes I get this two errors:

Case 1

```
Error calling Translate: {"fault":{"faultstring":"Gateway Timeout","detail":{"errorcode":"messaging.adaptors.http.flow.GatewayTimeout"}}}
```

Case 2 (when I try to rerun.):

```
{"Result":"Conflict","Diagnostic":"The request is rejected as it conflicts with a previous request that is in-progress."...
```

What I am doing wrong or what I should do?

Comment: Could you try again now?

Comment: Oh, as I said, I did run it a couple of times yesterday until it worked. So the post was done after I got a successful result. Yet I need to know what is happening and how to control it or fix it as the idea is to add it to production.... and let's be honest: unknown behaviour in prod is not the best.

Comment: Please see my reply below

Answer (score 0):

The network jitter might cause the `504 Gateway Timeout` error since it could not reproduce on your side now. If it occurs again, feel free to report to us via forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com.

Regarding the 409 Conflict error, it means that Forge service has accepted your previous request translation job and it's processing the job, but you request another translation job with `x-ads-force=true`, then it returns `409 Conflict`. if you retry without `x-ads-force=true`, then it will return 201 Created, according to our engineering team.

Hope it's clear enough to you.